# SVN Terminal Log in / Add files

Tags: svn, projectlocker

Im new to using SVN and Project locker. 
How do you log on through terminal?
Do I have to download svn on my mac?

Comment: svn comes by default to mac, I think. Try `man svn` on terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "login" with Subversion.  To avoid repeating the plethora of Subversion tutorials, here is a link that will walk you through this:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.importing.html

This link is part of the freely available book "Version Control with Subversion".  It's an amazing Subversion resource.